# Caught exception in Python still bubbling up

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

The following function looks for a file, and if it can't find it, compute something then writes to the file. It's basically a sort of naive caching system.

```
def get_result(param):
    try:
        result = get_file(param)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        result = compute_something(param)
        save_to_file(result)

    return result
```

This function is then queried from a different one:

```
def do_something(param):
    try:
        my_result = get_result(param)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception happened: {}".format(e.__class__.__name__))
```

Now let's try it, assuming that the cache file doesn't exist yet:

```
>>> do_something(my_param)
Exception happened: FileNotFoundError
```

How comes this `FileNotFoundError`, while caught in `get_result`, still bubbles up in `do_something`?

Comment: Probably because `save_to_file` throws another `FileNotFoundError`, but it's impossible to say for sure without a [mcve].

Comment: What does `save_to_file` do?

Comment: [crystal-ball] change the `"r"` inside your `save_to_file` to `"w"` ...?

Comment: this is abusing the try and catch mechanism. Why not checking if the file exists and do something if it doesnt using: `import os.path    if os.path.isfile(filepath):` or `if os.path.exists(path)`

Comment: @NotSoShabby No, this is not abuse at all. [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) is preferred over [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl). What if the file is deleted after your `isfile(...)` check, but before you've managed to actually open it?

Comment: I stand corrected. the force of a habit for me.